What does '一轉機' mean in this sentence?
I am reading a translation of Shakespeare's Hamlet, and in the preface, the translator says this:

旧訳は、それによって、國劇のセリフしの上に一轉機を招来しようという副目的があって物したのであったから、勢ひ狂言調などに泥み過ぎたのである。

I gather that the sentence loosely means "The old translation, composed in the Japanese theatrical elocution, with a secondary purpose of bring about a 'one rotation machine?', adheres too heavily to the Kyogen style."
This phrase, 一轉機 or 一回転機. It feels like an idiom or something that I am missing. Any ideas?

I don't think 一轉機 is a known yoji-jukugo. 一回 is "once", and 転機 is "turning point", so the literal meaning of 一回転機を招来する is "to bring about one (big) turning point". 一大転機 is a common yoji-jukugo similar to this.
This 一回転機 can be interpreted as referring to a turning point in this specific story, or to a new trend of the world of literature. Please judge based on the context.

旧訳は、それによって、國劇のセリフしの上に一轉機を招来しようという副目的があって物したのであったから、勢ひ狂言調などに泥み過ぎたのである。
The old translation was written with the secondary intent of creating a significant turning point on top of theatrical elocution, and thus was overly influenced by the style of Kyogen.

